# Dynamic O.O.P and instances

Tags: python, oop

**EDIT**

I m trying to make a function to dynamic change the object to get acess to those classes easier.

How can i pass the "test" variable inside that object?

I'v tryied this so far.

**EDIT**

```
class Vision:
    def find():
        pass

class visionInstances:
    visionPao = Vision(f'{PathMissionProducts}Pao.jpg')
    visionLeite = Vision(f'{PathMissionProducts}Leite.jpg')

xabuska = visionInstances() #Classe

def catch_screenshot(wincap):
    return wincap.get_screenshot()  

def getpoints(VisionInstanceName=None, threshold=0.7):
    test = VisionInstanceName
    points = xabuska.visionPao.find(catch_screenshot(xabuska.wincap),threshold,"points")
    points2 = xabuska.test.find(catch_screenshot(xabuska.wincap),threshold,"points")
    return points2
```

This code returns "None"

Note on the code that "xabuska.visionPao.find" are 3 diferent objects.
I want to make the second object "test" dynamic.

points1 = is the value i want.

points2 = is the test, and return None

Comment: Your question really isn't clear. Can you rephrase "How can i pass the "name" variable inside that object?". Also, you definitely should not be using `exec` here either, just `getattr(xabuska, name)`

Comment: Im acessing 3 instances.
xabuska = first instance,
{name} = chaging name for second instance,
find = third instance of the object,
Your code is just to get the name of xabuska right?

Comment: Again, your question is not clear at all. Please elaborate in the question itself, adding a full example.

Comment: There is only ONE instance in your code.  You can't have dynamic variable names in Python.  If you need that kind of thing, use a dictionary.  `pic['xabuska'] = visionInstances()`.

Comment: I'v edited the question. Maybe its a little clearer now.

Comment: OK, so again, this should just be `getattr(xabuska, name)` where `name` is a `str` of one of the attributes in the class `visionInstances`. As an aside, that really isn't a good use for a class. Generally, you would use a built-in container, like `list` or a `dict`, but in any case, if you *do* do it that way, `getattr` would work

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, Thanks for that. Im trying what you said. and could not find a solution yet. I tried test = getattr(xabuska,VisionInstanceName) and them using it in "xabuska.test.find...". And tried it directly, "xabuska.getattr(xabuska,VisionInstanceName).find...".
Is this syntax correct?